# Setting Authorization header in Angular 2

Tags: java, spring, angular, angular2-http

I am working on restful services in spring and I have implemented Json Web Token (JWT) for authentication and authorization. After login proper authentication token is returned to the requesting user. On every request I am checking the token in request header and validating the token. Code for filter is below.

```
@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    String authToken = request.getHeader(this.tokenHeader);
    System.out.println(authToken + "        ##########################");
    String username = flTokenUtil.getUsernameFromToken(authToken);
    if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
        UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
        if (flTokenUtil.validateToken(authToken, userDetails)) {
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
            authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        }
    }

    chain.doFilter(request, response);

}
```

And I am using angular 2 as frontend framework. Now when after getting authentication token I request for a secured resource using "**POSTMAN**" it works perfectly and token is received in the filter and all goes well. I am setting token in "Authorization" header.
Now the problem is when I do the same thing using angular 2 token is going null in the filter but firebug shows that  "Authorization" header is set and send successfully. I am doing this

```
    let token = "";
    if (undefined != this._tokenService.getToken()) {
        token = this._tokenService.getToken().getToken()
    }
    let header: Headers = new Headers();
    header.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    header.append('Authorization', token);
    let options = new RequestOptions({headers: header});

    return this.http.get(url, options)
       .map(res => {
          console.log(res.status)
          if (res.status == 200) {
              return res.json();
          } else if (res.status == 401) {
              return null;
          } else {
              throw new Error('This request has failed ' + res.status);
           }
        });
```

What I am doing wrong? What is the proper way to set header in angular 2. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: If you console.log the this._tokenService.getToken().getToken() is the token there?

Try debugging the request in chrome's developer tools, there you can see if the Authorization header is being sent properly.

Comment: yes token is set. I checked it.

Comment: also it is visible in request headers in firebug

Comment: The code will probably grow very fast... Consider using a library like angular2-rest https://github.com/DanielKucal/angular2-rest

Comment: Ever solved this? Have exactly the same problem.

Comment: @zszep I changed 'Authorization'  to 'X-Auth-Token' for header name and it works.

Comment: I don't see how changing 'Authorization' to 'X-Auth-Token' can solve the problem. Unless, you are requesting 'X-Auth-Token' instead of 'Authorization' at server side

Comment: `header.append('Authorization', token);` are you missing the bearer prefix? `header.append('Authorization', 'bearer' + ' '+ token);`

Answer (score 2):

If you want a more permanent solution I've got one for you.

By subclassing angular's http service you can inject the subclassed version and you then always get the headers added.

```
import {
  Http,
  ConnectionBackend,
  Headers,
  Request,
  RequestOptions,
  RequestOptionsArgs,
  Response,
  RequestMethod,
} from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { ErrorObservable } from 'rxjs/observable/ErrorObservable';

// A service that can get the logged in users jwt token as an observable
import { SecurityService } from './security.service';

// A service that handles cookies (angular2-cookie)
import { CookieService } from '../cookie';

/**
 * Custom Http client that handles conversions to json, adds CSRF token, and jwt token and redirects to signin if token is missing
 */
export class SecureHttp extends Http {

  constructor(
    backend: ConnectionBackend,
    defaultOptions: RequestOptions,
    private securityService: SecurityService,
    private cookieService: CookieService
  ) {
    super(backend, defaultOptions);
  }

  request(url: string | Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<any> {
    if (typeof url === 'string') {
      return this.get(url, options); // Recursion: transform url from String to Request
    }

    return this.sendRequest(url, options);
  }

  get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<any> {
    return this.sendRequest({ method: RequestMethod.Get, url: url, body: '' }, options);
  }

  post(url: string, body: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<any> {
    return this.sendRequest({ method: RequestMethod.Post, url: url, body: body }, options);
  }

  put(url: string, body: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<any> {
    return this.sendRequest({ method: RequestMethod.Put, url: url, body: body }, options);
  }

  delete(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<any> {
    return this.sendRequest({ method: RequestMethod.Delete, url: url, body: '' }, options);
  }

  patch(url: string, body: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<any> {
    return this.sendRequest({ method: RequestMethod.Patch, url: url, body: body }, options);
  }

  head(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<any> {
    return this.sendRequest({ method: RequestMethod.Head, url: url, body: '' }, options);
  }

  private sendRequest(requestOptionsArgs: RequestOptionsArgs, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<any> {

    let requestOptions = new RequestOptions(requestOptionsArgs);

    // Convert body to stringified json if it's not a string already
    if (typeof requestOptions.body !== 'string') {
      requestOptions.body = JSON.stringify(requestOptions.body);
    }

    // Get xsrf token from spring security cookie
    // by adding .csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
    const csrfToken: string = this.cookieService.get('XSRF-TOKEN');

    let baseOptions: RequestOptions = new RequestOptions({
      headers: new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        'X-XSRF-TOKEN': csrfToken
      })
    });

    return this.securityService.accessToken$.mergeMap(token => {

      // If there is a token we add it to the baseOptions
      if (token) {
        baseOptions.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
      }

      // We create a request from the passed in method, url, body and merge our base options in there
      let request = new Request(baseOptions.merge(requestOptions));

      return super.request(request, options)
        .map(res => res.json())
        .catch(this.errorHandler);
    });
  }

  private errorHandler(errorResponse: Response): Observable<any> | ErrorObservable {
    if (errorResponse.status === 401) {
      console.log('redirecting to login');
      window.location.href = '/login';
      return Observable.empty();
    }

    // If it's a serious problem we can log it to a service if we want to
    if (errorResponse.status === 500) {
      // this.errorReporter.logError(errorResponse);
    }

    console.error(errorResponse);

    return Observable.throw(errorResponse.text().length > 0 ? errorResponse.json() : { status: 'error' });
  }
}
```

Then in your module

```
export function secureHttpFactory(backend: XHRBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions, securityService: SecurityService, cookieService: CookieService) {
  return new SecureHttp(backend, defaultOptions, securityService, cookieService);
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    HttpModule,
    CookieModule,
    StorageModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
    ...DIRECTIVES,
    ...COMPONENTS,
  ],
  exports: [
    ...DIRECTIVES,
  ]
})
export class SecurityModule {

  // Only create on instance of these
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: SecurityModule,
      providers: [
        SecurityService,
        {
          provide: SecureHttp,
          useFactory: secureHttpFactory,
          deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions, SecurityService, CookieService]
        }
      ]
    };
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Bearer to you auth header and the content type header also like:

```
headers.append("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencode");
 headers.append("Authorization", "Bearer " + this.accessToken);
```

Comment: Shouldn't it also have a colon? `Bearer: <token>` or is that optional?

Comment: I think it is server side issue because first time when I request for login and that time token is null and filter received "Bearer" as token so it means token is received for login request but after that for other requests it is showing null on server side.

Comment: also token is visible in request headers in firebug

Comment: but i dont understand token is received when I make call from postman

Answer (score 0):

I followed alternative approach for it. 
appends token in URL and in filter i am splitting this token and use it for authentication. Also use request wrapper class and send original URL for further action.
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEP7X_7.0.4/com.ibm.wmqfte.doc/web_admin_servlet_filters.htm

Comment: For any answers, provide atleast short code (pseudo code will do) and for detailed analysis you can provide the helping links. The links do get changed over time, but your answer will be available always